# Reorder dictionary randomly

Tags: python, random, dictionary

Let's consider this dictionary

```
>>> test = {'to have': True, 'to get': False, 'having': False}
```

Imagine

```
>>> test.random_order()
{'having': False, 'to get': False, 'to have': True}
```

How can I reorder it randomly? Should I use `OrderedDict` and `random.shuffle`? If so, how can I combine them?

Comment: I finally used lists instead of dicts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just shuffle the key/value pairs (items) and pass them on to `OrderedDict`:

```
items = test.items()
random.shuffle(items)
OrderedDict(items)
```

Comment: It will not update the dictionary, will it ? `random.shuffle()` returns nothing

Comment: Oh yes, that's true, sorry! Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Your question does not make sense in a strict sense — a dictionary is a *mapping* from a **set** of keys to a **set** of values. As such, they don't have an order since sets don't have order. The order you see when you print a dictionary is "random" and not to be trusted. You can see the randomness in action when you use the `-R` flag with a modern Python:

```
$ python -R -c 'print dict(foo=10, bar=20, baz=30)'
{'baz': 30, 'foo': 10, 'bar': 20}
$ python -R -c 'print dict(foo=10, bar=20, baz=30)'
{'foo': 10, 'baz': 30, 'bar': 20}
```

Instead of using a dictionary, I think you should a list since that datastructure has an order. If you start with a `dict`, then use

```
items = test.items()
random.shuffle(items)
```

to get a list of shuffled `(key, value)` pairs. You can pass those to `OrderedDict` and that will give you a dictionary where the keys have an order associated with them.

Comment: I understand the lake of coherence. I think I should use a list instead.

Comment: Using lists instead of dicts simplified my life on this issue :) Thanks.

Comment: How specifically is using lists better than dicts here?

Comment: @darkmango Lists are ordered, and dictionaries are not. So when you want to shuffle something, lists work better.

Comment: Why would they work better? (I don't see how being ordered in the first place matters since the data can be shuffled either way)

Comment: @darkmango Without a data structure that keeps ordering, it's hard to talk about "shuffling" the data in the first place. You could have a non-deterministic data structure where `pop` would look at all its elements and pick a random one to return. However, I think "picking a random one" also needs some ordering: you would typically put the elements into a list and generate a random list index.